# Bulirsch-Stoer method implemented in C++

Tags: c++

I need to do an N body simulation using Bulirsch-Stoer method. I tried to do it for 2 bodies using this code in C++:

```
void update(Body b){
        initial_x=rx;
        initial_y=ry;
        initial_vx=vx;
        initial_vy=vy;
        dx=b.rx-initial_x;
        dy=b.ry-initial_y;
        dist = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
        ax=G*b.mass*(b.rx-initial_x)/(dist*dist*dist);
        ay=G*b.mass*(b.ry-initial_y)/(dist*dist*dist);

        for(n=2;n<=8;n=n+2){
            h=H/n;
            vec_x[0]=initial_x+h*initial_vx;
            vec_y[0]=initial_y+h*initial_vy;
            vx=vx+h*ax;
            vy=vy+h*ay;
            dx=b.rx-vec_x[0];
            dy=b.ry-vec_y[0];
            dist = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
            ax=G*b.mass*(b.rx-vec_x[0])/(dist*dist*dist);
            ay=G*b.mass*(b.ry-vec_y[0])/(dist*dist*dist);
            vec_x[1]=initial_x+2*h*vx;
            vec_y[1]=initial_y+2*h*vy;
            vx=vx+h*ax;
            vy=vy+h*ay;
            dx=b.rx-vec_x[1];
            dy=b.ry-vec_y[1];
            dist = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
            ax=G*b.mass*(b.rx-vec_x[1])/(dist*dist*dist);
            ay=G*b.mass*(b.ry-vec_y[1])/(dist*dist*dist);
            if (n>2){
                for(int i=2;i<n;i++){
                    vec_x[i]=vec_x[i-2]+2*h*vx;
                    vec_y[i]=vec_y[i-2]+2*h*vy;
                    vx=vx+h*ax;
                    vy=vy+h*ay;
                    dx=b.rx-vec_x[i];
                    dy=b.ry-vec_y[i];
                    dist = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
                    ax=G*b.mass*(b.rx-vec_x[i])/(dist*dist*dist);
                    ay=G*b.mass*(b.ry-vec_y[i])/(dist*dist*dist);

                }
            }
            rx=0.5*(vec_x[n-2]+vec_x[n-1]+h*vx);
            ry=0.5*(vec_y[n-2]+vec_y[n-1]+h*vy);
            Rx[n/2-1]=rx;
            Ry[n/2-1]=ry;
        }

        rx=Rx[0]*(-H/4)*(-H/6)*(-H/8)/((H/2-H/4)*(H/2-H/6)*(H/2-H/8))+Rx[1]*(-H/2)*(-H/6)*(-H/8)/((H/4-H/2)*(H/4-H/6)*(H/4-H/8))+Rx[2]*(-H/2)*(-H/4)*(-H/8)/((H/6-H/2)*(H/6-H/4)*(H/6-H/8))+Rx[3]*(-H/2)*(-H/4)*(-H/6)/((H/8-H/2)*(H/8-H/4)*(H/8-H/6));
        ry=Ry[0]*(-H/4)*(-H/6)*(-H/8)/((H/2-H/4)*(H/2-H/6)*(H/2-H/8))+Ry[1]*(-H/2)*(-H/6)*(-H/8)/((H/4-H/2)*(H/4-H/6)*(H/4-H/8))+Ry[2]*(-H/2)*(-H/4)*(-H/8)/((H/6-H/2)*(H/6-H/4)*(H/6-H/8))+Ry[3]*(-H/2)*(-H/4)*(-H/6)/((H/8-H/2)*(H/8-H/4)*(H/8-H/6));
    }
```

So basically I calculated the next step for n=2,4,6,8 and then I interpolate, and take that value as the new rx and ry (this is just the function I am interested about, I didn't put the whole program). So I saved the rx and ry in a file and plotted y(x) and I got this:

[image]

I am supposed to get a circle around (0,0). I tried the whole day to see what is wrong. I am not sure if it is a coding error or I am just not implementing the method properly but I really need help.

Comment: It looks like you have rounding errors which cause the trajectory to deteriorate. You need to ask a question at a more suitable forum, you won't get much help with numerical simulations here.

Comment: My suggestion would be not to implement Burlish-Stoer by yourself (as with any other complicated stepping algorithm). Instead, I'd rely on the Numerical Recipes implementation ... or forget about all these heavy methods which in my experience give you a constant (often smaller than the time to make them run).

Comment: @davidhigh The code suggests it's a simulation of a gravitational systems. Such problems are notorious for losing accuracy over longer times. IMHO the best thing to do would be to rephrase the problem in terms of conserved quantities (total energy, angular momentum) and go from there (or at least monitor their values). It's not easy.

Comment: I didn't check your implementation, but the fact that the orbit decays hilariously fast (falls into the star under two orbits) leads me to think that you didn't give the secondary enough velocity to maintain its orbit. Yes, unless you take care in picking a good integrator, you loss energy over time (but that is generally over thousands of orbits, not two). For a circular orbit the initial velocity should be $v_x = 0$ and $v_y =  v_K$ the Keplerian velocity, which is $v_K = \sqrt(GM_*/a)$, where $M_*$ is the mass of the central body, and $a$ is the semi-major axis of the orbiting body.